# phone gap cordova installation

Tags: json, node.js, cordova

I'm trying to install phonegap but getting following error message. I have tried this for cordova also but of no use, Please help me

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (x64) and npm.

C:\Users\saiki>install -g phonegap
'install' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\saiki>npm install -g phonegap
/


> ws@0.4.31 install C:\Users\saiki\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\nod
e_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_mo
dules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

\
C:\Users\saiki\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-ph
onegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws>node "C:\Pr
ogram Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\n
ode-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
/
> ws@0.4.31 install C:\Users\saiki\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\nod
e_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\
node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\Users\saiki\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-ph
onegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.
io-client\node_modules\ws>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\b
in\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\saiki\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\lodash\2.4.1\package\pac
kage.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\saiki
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! file C:\Users\saiki\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\lodash\2.4.1\package\pack
age.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! not ok code 0

C:\Users\saiki>
```

please reply me as soon as possible. 
Some text to make this post work or just to get submitted

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you trying > install -g phonegap on window? please install phonegap for window

Comment: no I tried install using command >npm install -g phonegap